# Cloudformation - environment variable used when condition is met

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I need to pass different variables based on environment of my lambda function. Created below condition but getting error when trying to use `!If`. Appreciate all the help and suggestions on how to workaround this.

Error while deployment:

```
Properties validation failed for resource LambdaFunction
```

YML file:

```
Conditions:
  IsProd: !Equals [!Ref AppEnv, "production"]
  IsNonProd: !Not [!Equals [!Ref AppEnv, "production"]]

  LambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    DependsOn:
      - LambdaLayer
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Sub '${AppName}-${AppEnv}'
      Handler: function.handler
      Layers:
        - !Ref LambdaLayer
      VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - Ref: SecurityGroup
        SubnetIds:
          - Ref: PrivateSubnetAz1
          - Ref: PrivateSubnetAz2
      Code:
        S3Bucket: !Sub 'app-deploy-${AWS::AccountId}-${AWS::Region}'
        S3Key: !Ref S3LambdaKey
      Environment:
        Variables:
          !If
            - "IsNonProd"
            - 
              - DD_SITE: !GetAtt EncryptedDDSite.CipherText
              - DD_API_KEY: !GetAtt EncryptedDDApiKey.CipherText
              - USER_DEV: !GetAtt EncryptedUserDev.CipherText
              - PASS_DEV: !GetAtt EncryptedPassDev.CipherText
              - USER_STG: !GetAtt EncryptedUserStg.CipherText
              - PASS_STG: !GetAtt EncryptedPassStg.CipherText
              - USER_TEST: !GetAtt EncryptedUserTest.CipherText
              - PASS_TEST: !GetAtt EncryptedPassTest.CipherText
              - AppEnv: !Ref AppEnv
            - 
              - DD_SITE: !GetAtt EncryptedDDSite.CipherText
              - DD_API_KEY: !GetAtt EncryptedDDApiKey.CipherText
              - USER_PRD: !GetAtt EncryptedUserPrd.CipherText
              - PASS_PRD: !GetAtt EncryptedPassPrd.CipherText
              - AppEnv: !Ref AppEnv
      Runtime: python3.8
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 300
      Role: !GetAtt
        - LambdaRole
        - Arn
```

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: `Json parsing exception message = Unrecognized token 'AWSTemplateFormatVersion': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null') at [ Yaml parsing exception message = while parsing a block mapping in 'reader', line 339, column 9:            Variables:            ^expected <block end>, but found '<block mapping start>' in 'reader', line 356, column 11:              AppEnv: !Ref AppEnv              ^ at [`

Comment: What's in your template's [parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html) section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!If` requires an array and the second and third items should also be an array. Also AppEnv must be added twice.

```
  Environment:
    Variables:
      !If:
        - "IsNonProd"
        - 
          - DD_SITE: !GetAtt EncryptedDDSite.CipherText
          - DD_API_KEY: !GetAtt EncryptedDDApiKey.CipherText
          - USER_DEV: !GetAtt EncryptedUserDev.CipherText
          - PASS_DEV: !GetAtt EncryptedPassDev.CipherText
          - USER_STG: !GetAtt EncryptedUserStg.CipherText
          - PASS_STG: !GetAtt EncryptedPassStg.CipherText
          - USER_TEST: !GetAtt EncryptedUserTest.CipherText
          - PASS_TEST: !GetAtt EncryptedPassTest.CipherText
          - AppEnv: !Ref AppEnv
        - 
          - DD_SITE: !GetAtt EncryptedDDSite.CipherText
          - DD_API_KEY: !GetAtt EncryptedDDApiKey.CipherText
          - USER_PRD: !GetAtt EncryptedUserPrd.CipherText
          - PASS_PRD: !GetAtt EncryptedPassPrd.CipherText
          - AppEnv: !Ref AppEnv
```

Comment: Got similar error: `Json parsing exception message = Unrecognized token 'AWSTemplateFormatVersion': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null') at [ Yaml parsing exception message = while parsing a block mapping in 'reader', line 338, column 9:            Variables:            ^expected <block end>, but found '<block mapping start>' in 'reader', line 355, column 11:              AppEnv: !Ref AppEnv              ^ at [`

Comment: You need to add AppEnv in both lists.

Comment: Thas is a miss. New error `YAML not well-formed. (line 339, column 11)`

Comment: Post your new code. Most probably you have an indentation issue.

Comment: Updated code added to the post.

Comment: The YAML looks good. Paste your code into http://www.yamllint.com/ or another service and test it. Check that you are using spaces everywhere and no tabs.

Comment: lint shows template to be ok, will do some more investigation

Comment: `!If` instead of `!If:` ;)

Comment: Build went ok but deployment threw error: `Properties validation failed for resource LambdaFunction`

Comment: Things to check: Name isn't longer than 64 characters. Security groups and subnets exist. Lambda layer valid.